# how to reset vim's settings (including plugins, .vimrc file) without close vim?

Tags: editor, vim

I have been using vim for two years, and I use "pathogen" for plugins manage. I am seeking 
a way to reset all vim's settings (including plugins, .vimrc file) without close vim. Is 
there any idea?

PS: In some cases, reload vimrc doesnot work exactly the same as reopen vim, so I want to 
reload the whole state exactly like reopen vim.

Comment: Why are you wanting to reload Vim's state w/o actually reopening vim? Why not reopen vim? Will making a session via `:mksession` and restrarting vim via `vim -S session.vim` good enough? Is reloading plugins really necessary?

Answer (score 8):

From `:h set`

```
:se[t] all&             Set all options, except terminal options, to their
                            default value.  The values of 'term', 'lines' and
                            'columns' are not changed. {not in Vi}
```

Comment: After resetting all options, you might want to `:source $MYVIMRC` and `:runtime! plugin/**/*.vim`.  Basically, run through the steps described at `:help startup`.

Comment: @benjifisher I doubt most plugins will be truly be reloaded. It is commonplace to add a guard to prevent just such a thing. You could use something like [scriptease](https://github.com/tpope/vim-scriptease)'s `:Runtime` command to "disarm" the guards and then does a `:runtime!`. However my concerns do not end there as there are many more things that may need to be torn down and then built back up, e.g. `autocmd`'s, mappings, functions, and commands.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear why would you avoid restarting Vim.

If the problem is to lose the current state of tabpages, windows and buffers it would be preferable to create a session to save what matters and the reload everything else.

Building on Peter Rincker suggestion on the comments, there is a [great plugin called session.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3150), which makes managing sessions very easy. It also creates the [Restart command](http://peterodding.com/code/vim/session/):

> This command saves your current editing session, restarts Vim and
>   restores your editing session. This can come in handy when you’re
>   debugging Vim scripts which can’t be easily/safely [reloaded using a
>   more lightweight approach](http://peterodding.com/code/vim/reload/).

The `:Restart` command worked very well here, so I've never tested the other plugin for the "lightweight approach". But you could try it if completely restarting Vim is not an option.

Comment: I am pretty understand why the author avoid restarting Vim, it may because the author want to add a new vim plugin or something else, which bother me the same for a long time