# What has changed my mouse selection behaviour?

Tags: linux, vim

In using vim on Linux at the terminal I expect mouse selection to behave as (e.g.):

- Start insert mode
- Select some other text with left mouse button
- Click middle button
- Selected text gets pasted in where I was inserting

I think of this as "normal terminal mouse behaviour", and expect it to work like that for all programs, not just vim. However, something changed in the past few days and vim now acts differently:

- Start insert mode
- Select some other text with left mouse button

  - My insertion point now moves to the start of the selection
  - My mode is changed from "Insert" to "(insert) SELECT"
- Click middle button
- Looks like nothing happened, but I think it has actually pasted the selection on top of itself, because if I click again the selected text appears a second time after the selection.

One other symptom: The mouse cursor is now an arrow when pointing at a vim terminal window. Other terminal windows show [an I beam](http://www.hal-pc.org/journal/2006/06_novDec/images/mel_image006.jpg), and vim used to do that too.

This is a problem with vim, not terminal because

1. It behaves the same in Gnome terminal, Konsole, and Terminator
2. Other programs at terminal behave the "normal" way

I have tried changing settings for `:behave`, `:set selectmode` and `:set mouse`, but this has not helped (maybe I just haven't found the right combo yet?).

This problem is recent (this week), but I have not [changed my vim settings](https://github.com/jalanb/dotjab/commits/master/vim/vimrc) relevantly in that time.

Any ideas as to what's going on here?

Comment: Did you try `:set mouse=a`?

Comment: @iqstatic Yes I tried `:set mouse=a` but it makes no difference

Comment: In that case you can reset the vim editor as shown in this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22162858/how-to-reset-vims-settings-including-plugins-vimrc-file-without-close-vim. You already have a `vimrc` which you can use to restore to your current settings.

Comment: @iqstatic Having reset the editor I cannot do any selection at all, then doing `set mouse=a` brings back the current behaviour (mouse starts SELECT mode)

Comment: What version of vim are you using?

Comment: Vi Improved 7.4 (2013 Aug 10 compiled June 26 2014). Included patches 1-345. Compiled by me on this machine

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62593/discussion-between-iqstatic-and-jalanb).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command `:set mouse=a` suggested should enable mouse integration in all modes but this is not what you want. To stop VIM messing with the mouse settings use `:set mouse=` (with no letters after the equals) to prevent it from changing the mouse in any mode.

Comment: This is a company machine, and IT changed /etc/vim/vimrc to include `set mouse=a`. Fixed at https://github.com/jalanb/dotjab/commit/16473d46e20ef27d4506576270168ea68bf075f8